# MS application is asking for authentication multiple times

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Recently I am working with MS Graph with Office 365 to create some application. I am using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0` as authentication point. Until few days back it was worked fine as when I run the application it is asking for authentication when I provide the user name password details then it is going to my website. I don't know what happened, from last one week it is keep on asking password for multiple time. When I click on back button then it is going back to my site with authenticated screen.

[image]

I have registered my app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com already with proper permissions.

Comment: There isn't enough info here to go on. You need to provide some details about how you're sending them to the authorization endpoint, the parameters your sending and ideally, an HTTP trace showing what is going up and down the wire.

Comment: Yeah true, but to enter all those details I don't know this place is sufficient or not. I am following https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample sample for authentication

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing the details or traces, there isn't a lot I can tell from here.

Comment: Shall I include the code here?

Comment: Yes, your question should include code samples, https traces, tokens, etc. Anything that can be used to help diagnose what is happening and help future readers to self-diagnose when they run into a similar issue.